# Array index out of bound exception how to overcome

Tags: java

```
public void updateGoalPositions(Goal[][] goals)
{    
int row=(goals.length-1);
int col=(goals[0].length-1);

for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
    {
        if(goals[i][j+1].isHit())
        {
            Goal temp=goals[i][j+1];
            goals[i][j+1]=goals[i][j];
            goals[i][j]=temp;
        }
        else
            if(goals[i][j-1].isHit())
            {
                Goal temp=goals[i][j-1];
                goals[i][j-1]=goals[i][j];
                goals[i][j]=temp;
            }
    }          
}
```

`goals[i][j-1]` shows error. How to override it?

Comment: sure that `goals[i][j+1]` is not the problem?

Comment: Check the back-trace and find, which line is giving the error.

Comment: If `j = 0` you'll be trying to access `goals[0][-1]`, no?

Comment: When J is 0 and it goes to else then it becomes -1.  which is not valid index.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately, your question misses some of the elements we like to see here. Please make sure you provide some detail about the efforts you took in solving this problem. Also, provide detailed error messages. Do not just dump code at us and ask us to solve your problem.

Comment: He didn't just dump code, he posted code with a specific problem, the line on which it was occurring and asked how to fix it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when j = 0, j - 1 gives -1 which causes the error so test condition only if j - 1 >= 0

```
else
    if(j - 1 >= 0 && goals[i][j-1].isHit())
    {
        Goal temp=goals[i][j-1];
        goals[i][j-1]=goals[i][j];
        goals[i][j]=temp;
    }
```

Comment: @Karan You might also want to set `int row=(goals.length-1);` to `int row=(goals.length);` as last row will not be checked.

Answer (score 1):

Everywhere you have `j+1` you'll exceed the limit in the last iteration.

Why? Because arrays are *zero-based* in Java, meaning that if you have an array of size `N`, the indexes will run between `[0, N-1]`. In your last iteration, when `j` is `N-1`, `j+1` is actually `N`, which is out of bounds.

Read about arrays in the [JLS - Chapter 10. Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html).

Note also that you have places where `j-1` will be -1 (in the first iteration where `j` is 0).

Answer (score 1):

On first j-iteration, j=0 and j-1's value is -1
Add `if (j-1>-1)` for example

Answer (score 1):

When `i = 0` and `j = 0`, `goals[i][j-1]` is going to mean `goals[0][-1]` that is your issue, you need to fix your algorithm.